# Drupal 6 $key => $value form #options array built using while loop where $key = $value

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to build an array of $key => $values using a while loop where the $key is equal to the value, from a db_query. I think the syntax isn't correct

```
function _form(){

$person = db_query("SELECT name FROM {person}");                 
$columnValues = Array();

while ($row = db_fetch_array($person) ) {
  $columnValues[] = array($row['name']=> $row['name']);
}
.
.
.
```

I have a few questions.

1. do i need to create a key to pull out the actual 'select' menu item value?
2. if i need to create a key, is there a way in the while loop to not create a new array for each element that is keyed by its same value (eg. apple => apple)
3. what is the correct way to pull out values from checkboxes and from select so i get a string and not an ordered number? (eg. form_values['value']['select_name'] , form_values['value']['checkboxes_name']  so that first returns selected item 'apple' and second gives checked item 'apple'.)  ... i like apples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be making a mistake here - in the key value pair, the value cannot be an array

```
while ($row = db_fetch_array($person) ) {
   $columnValues[] = array($row['name']=> $row['name']);
}
```

should be

```
while ($row = db_fetch_array($person) ) {
   $columnValues[$row['name']] = $row['name'];
}
```

Answers:

1. Yes, you should always add a key value pair - as value is what gets displayed and key is what gets submitted in the form submit.
2. Yes the above explains how you should create key => value pair and not an array of key => value pairs for each item.
3. Individual checkbox items have values and you can set the value of checkbox to be the same as that of the display.